# UIBarButtonItem to Storyboard View

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButton item in a seperate xib file but when that button is pressed i want to take it to a view on my storyboard.

I can go from a storyboard view (when a round rect button is pressed) to a seperate,custom xib file view. But i can't go back (using either a round rect button or uibarbuttonitem).

Can someone help please?

Comment: Are you pushing a seque, or displaying it modally?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't put the view in the separate XIB file into the storyboard?

Comment: @MarkS. how can i put the separate XIB files into the storyboard?

Comment: @JamesPaolantonio when going from storyboard to separate xib file I use the following code:

-(IBaction)button {
MainViewController *viewOther = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:viewOther.view];
[THISViewController release];
}

works perfect to go to the separate xib file.

just can't go back using the UIBarButtonItem I added onto my separate xib to the storyboard viewcontroller

Comment: Do you want to instantiate a new view from your storyboard view or do you want to go to a view on your storyboard that is already being displayed?

Comment: @JustinPaulson i want to go to a view on my storyboard that is already being displayed from the xib file i have

Comment: Is it the view that created this xib or is it a different view?  Is it on a navigationController stack?

Comment: @JustinPaulson I have a view I created on storyboard that goes to a seperate xib file(not on storyboard) when a uibutton is pressed but I want the separate xib file(not on storyboard) to be able to go back to the view on the storyboard when a UIBarButtonItem is pressed

Comment: If you just want it to go back to the same view that presented it, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used this code to create the view from xib:

```
-(IBaction)button { 
    MainViewController *viewOther = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
    [self.view addSubview:viewOther.view]; 
    [THISViewController release]; 
}
```

Then just do this in your new sub view controller to remove it and "go back" to the view on the storyboard:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

However, I don't think this is the best method to handle this at all.  I would have presented the new `viewController` as a `modalViewController` and then dismissed it when it was done using this:

present it:

```
-(IBaction)button { 
    MainViewController *viewOther = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewOther animated:YES];
}
```

and then release it using this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However, this is still not really the best way to do it.  The BEST way to do it is to create a delegate in the `MainViewController` and then have the storyboard view controller assign itself as the delegate of the `MainViewController`.  Then when the button is pressed, the `MainViewController` should tell its `delegate` (the storyboard view controller) to dismiss it, then the storyboard view controller will dismiss the `MainViewController`.  That takes a little too long to explain though, especially if you are unfamiliar with creating a protocol.